# Programming Java on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, java, programming, jdk

I have ubuntu 13.10 and I am trying to use a disk that contains a book, *How to program Java*, 7th edition. It is the Linux version CD and I can't figure out what program to use so I can look at the files on it.

All of the files are in `.class` format. I have used the windows version on another pc and it seems to work fine with `jgrasp`, is there something else I should be using to edit and create java programs with the `.class` extension?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? An IDE? Any old text editor can open `.class` files iirc.

Comment: any editor that would open .class files. I can't seem to open any of the .class files. I am about ready to just give up.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest you have HelloWorld.class file inside some directory. To run it, you simply should type in this directory:

```
java HelloWorld
```

To run jar archive, use `-jar` key:

```
java -jar MyProgram.jar
```

To select java machine, type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

To install Oracle JDK:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-jdk7-installer
```

After installation, you can select it as default java.